# vuejs 3 pinia unable to access data from store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuex, pinia

I am using Pinia for the first time. I am implemeting login feature with backend api which returns userId, I want store this userId in store and want to access it anywhere in vue component.
Currently,I am not able to access the userId from store, it does not print the userId in vue template.
Here is my code:
Sores/user.js

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import axios from 'axios'

export const useUserStore = defineStore({
  id: 'user',
  state: () => ({
    userId:null ,
 
  }),
  actions: {
    login({ email, password }) {
        axios.post('/user/login', { email: email, password: password }).then((res) => {
            console.log('res',res.data.userId)
            this.userId = res.data.userId
         

        }).catch((error)=>alert('error'))
    },
    
  }
})
```

Login.vue

```
<script setup>
import axios from 'axios';
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { useUserStore } from '@/stores/user'
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';

const email = ref('');
const password = ref('');

const userStore = useUserStore();
const router = useRouter();

const login = () => {
    userStore.login({ email: email.value, password: password.value });
    router.push('/dashboard')
}
</script>
```

Dashboard.vue
here it want to print userId from store

```
<template>
    <div id="dashboard">
        <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4">
           
            <Header />
            {{ userStore.userId }}

        </div>
    
        </div>
    </div>
</template>


<script setup>
import Header from './Header.vue'
import { useUserStore } from '@/stores/user'
const userStore = useUserStore()
</script>
```

Comment: If you inspect or add a ```console.log(this.userId)``` inside the action login (after you'r assign this) what do you see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```js
const login = () => {
  userStore.login({ email: email.value, password: password.value });
  router.push('/dashboard')
}
```

You're pushing the change of route before logging in. You want to wait for the login request's response, then change the route, either with `async/await`:

```js
const login = async () => {
  await userStore.login({ email: email.value, password: password.value })
  router.push("/dashboard")
}
```

... or with `.then()`:

```js
const login = () => {
  userStore.login({ email: email.value, password: password.value }).then(() => {
    router.push("/dashboard")
  })
}
```

---

Note the `login()` action on userStore needs to return a promise.

Either `return` the axios call (which is already a promise):

```js
  //...
  actions: {
    login({ email, password }) {
      return axios.post(//...
```

...or *"promisify"* the action using `async/await`:

```js
  //...
  actions: {
    async login({ email, password }) {
      await axios.post(//...
```

Comment: Hi @tao, still no luck, i followed your above steps
`const login = async () => {
    await userStore.login({ email: email.value, password: password.value });
    router.push({ path: '/dashboard' })
}`
and
`  actions: {
    async login({ email, password }) {
        await axios.post('/user/login', { email: email, password: password }).then((res) => {
            console.log('res',res.data.userId,res.data.userRole)
            this.userId = 1
            this.userRole = res.data.userRole

        }).catch((error)=>alert('error'))
    },`

Comment: You don't need luck for this. But if you need my help further, you'll need to create a *runnable* [mcve] where I could follow your code through and potentially spot what's amiss. Consider using codesandbox.io or similar (note codesandbox allows you to [import local projects with ease](https://codesandbox.io/docs/learn/getting-started/your-first-sandbox#import-local-projects-via-cli)). What is the exact response from server?

Comment: Also, I just noticed in your code above you're trying to set some `userRole`. You have to declare all state properties ***up-front***. If you don't set an initial `state.userRole` and then assign one `this.userRole = 'whatever'`, it's not going to be reactive. In other words, this change won't be propagated to components reading the store.

Comment: Don't worry about not being to repro the backend on codesandbox. We can replace the backend with a mock (a function returning the expected response after a short wait), and make sure the frontend code is working properly. Once that's done, if your local project is still not working, we'll need to take a look at your backend and see what it returns and why.

Comment: my state is like this ` state: () => ({
    userId:null ,
    userRole:null
  }),
`
My api returns user id and role name once user is logged in
Even if i hard code the response like this
 this.userId = 1
            this.userRole = 'admin'
They are not set in state because i am not able to access state value in other components

Comment: Have hooked up pinia to the app? Have a quick look [at this](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-wood-bpf05k?file=/src/store/user.js). You have to call `pinia = createPinia()` and tell the app to use it: `app.use(pinia)`. Also, in case you started your dev instance ***before*** you installed pinia, you have to restart it before pinia actually starts working. Just restart the dev server.

Comment: yes I have pinia store. One thing I am suprised is if I hard code data in state like this
  state: () => ({
    userId:1 ,
    userRole:'admin'
  }),
I am able to access userId and userRole in any components

Comment: It sounds like there's something wrong with your store setup. I won't be able to tell you what's wrong with code you're not showing. Please create a *runnable* [mcve] (e.g: an actual sandbox, like the one I linked above).